# How to build click time picker - jquery

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I've got a client who requires a custom build timepicker. It has to be simple - just a circle which takes the position of the mouse cursor on click and translate it to time.

I know how to get cursor position relatively to the element (circle) and then I'm thinking that if I can calculate an angle between time 00:00 and a line which goes through middle of a circle and a cursor position it should be pretty easy to translate to time.

Any idea how to do this? Maybe there is another way of creating such a timepicker?

Comment: Do you need to calculate minutes? How close does it need to be in time?

Comment: Yes I have to calculate a minutes too

Comment: Really, your client wants it to be clock based? Have they even considered mobile and tablet devices? Better off using an already made solution - http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/

Answer (score 0):

I would build an hour picker and a minute picker separately. Like Android Kit Kat has.

I would build the clock, absolute positioning your items onload with css. Breakdown each hour into it's own element so when the user clicks, you know what hour it is.

```
<ul id="hour">
   <li>12</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   ....
</ul>
```

Once user initiates click event, hide hour and build/display minutes clock broken down every 5 mins.

```
<ul id="minutes">
    <li>00</li>
    <li>05</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>15</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Assign click events

```
 $('#hour li, #minutes li').click(function(e) {
      console.log($(e.target).val());
      // do whatever
 });
```

Comment: Thanks papa but client wants 1 click timepicker.

Comment: You still essentially need to log two clicks, one for hour and one for minute. There are two hands on a clock.

Comment: Not really. I can calculate a minutes from the distance between hours. So if user clicks exactly between 1 a clock and 2 a clock it makes it 1:30

Comment: That's not 1:30. That's 1:07. Too much user error to have. Need to click right here just to get the right time.

Comment: Client want it to be 1:30. Think of a clock with just 1 arm.